# AJAX long response is not displaying by using inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, innerhtml

I have prepared some forum list by AJAX call
- forum list prepared successfully at server side [seems in log] 
- but while trying to display by changing inner html

code snippet used to change inner html :

```
$("#loadforumAJAX").html( {generated forum list });
```

- if there is 10-20 forums in list then its working fine
- but while printing all forum list by inner html then it's not working
- also there is no any JavaScript error on console

is there any data limit for use inner html ?

So please help me for the same or suggested way how to debug this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: do a console.log({generated forum list }) and show us. Maybe you have a HTML error

Comment: Can you post the ajax block as well? I'd need to see how you're reading the `generated forum list` before providing suggestions on the fix.

Comment: this is not enough code

Comment: AJAX function call :$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"$contextPath/jforum${extension}?module=ajax&action=loadForums",
   data:params,
   dataType:"script",
   global:false
  });     After this function call i have set all response to .js template as we can do it in jforum

Comment: What do you mean, dataType:"script"?  This means the Ajax response-text is a javascrip file (or so).  Is it?  If not, try without that line (comment it out)